# Get Keyboard Interrupt in C

Tags: c, linux, unix, keyboard, signal-handling

Program:

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
    int time=1800;
    while(1){
        system("clear");
        time-=1;
        printf("%d\n",time);
        sleep(1);
    if(time==0)
        pause();
    }
}
```

The above program stops when the time reaches 0. My requirement is during the runtime of the program, If I press any key like spacebar or any other key, the program gets paused and once again I press the key, the program gets resumed. So for doing this, before execution of 
while condition, we submit the signal handler for keyboard interrupt. In C how to do this.

What is the function used to get keyboard interrupt. I dont want to get input from the user, I want to handle the interrupt generated by the user through keyboard.

Thanks in Advance..,

Comment: What Operating System?

Comment: use sighandler_t signal(int signum, sighandler_t handler);

Comment: There is a  library signal.h to use signals and their handling. Use that and ^this.

Comment: @venki and vish4071 Please expand on how signals can be used to get keyboard presses. There isn't a way that I know of. Signals can be used to catch certain key combinations such as ctrl-c. But the question seems to be about getting arbitrary key presses.

Comment: On Linux you can receive key presses via the Input subsystem. Read about it [here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/input/input.txt). Basically an input device is opened such as `/dev/input/event0` which corresponds to the keyboard device. Then events can be read from that device. Each key press and release will generate an event.

Comment: ctrl and c are not keyboard keys?

Comment: I want to handle the interrupt generated by the user through keyboard what does this line means

Comment: @venki They are keyboard keys. But they are not the **only** keyboard keys. Simple example, how to get a signal when the user presses space bar?

Comment: spacebar will not generate interrupt check question again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88754/discussion-between-venki-and-alan-au).

Comment: mohan + @alanau: http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/chp-6-sect-4

Answer (score 4):

The keyboard does not exist in purely standard C99 or C11 (*stdin* is not a keyboard, and could be a [pipe(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html) so is not always a [tty(4)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/tty.4.html); you might read from `/dev/tty` ...).

So it is much less simple that what you want it to be, and it is operating system specific. I am focusing on Linux.

Read much more about ttys, notably read the [tty demystified](http://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/). Notice that tty are usually in cooked mode, where the *kernel* is buffering lines (in addition of *stdin* being line buffered).

The reasonable way is to use a terminal library like [ncurses](https://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/) or [readline](http://www.gnu.org/software/readline). These libraries are setting the tty in raw mode (which you might do by yourself, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13104460/841108) and [termios(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/termios.3.html); you'll probably need also to [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html)). Be sure to exit properly and reset the tty to cooked mode before exiting.

But your life is probably too short to dive into [termios(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/termios.3.html) and [tty_ioctl(4)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/tty_ioctl.4.html) so just use `ncurses` or `readline`

You could also consider some GUI application (e.g. above [X11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X11) or [Wayland](http://wayland.freedesktop.org/)). Then use a toolkit ([GTK](http://gtk.org/), [Qt](http://qt.io/), ...).

Answer (score 4):

You need conio.h for your requirement.It defines kbhit() and getch() both wait for input from keyboard.

Whenever kbhit() is called, it checks the keyboard buffer and returns a nonzero value if the buffer has any keypress otherwise 0 is returned.

The conio.h is used by MSDOS compilers and is not the part of standard C libraries (ISO). It is also not defined in POSIX.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

int main()
{
   while(1)
   {
       while(!kbhit())
       {
          //works continuously until interrupted by keyboard input.
          printf("M Tired. Break Me\n");
       }
       getch();
   }
   return 0;
}
```

For linux you may use the following snippet to implement kbhit() by using fnctl() from fnctl.h for signal handling:

```
  #include <termios.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <fcntl.h>


        int kbhit(void)
        {
          struct termios oldt, newt;
          int ch;
          int oldf;

          tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, &oldt);
          newt = oldt;
          newt.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON | ECHO);
          tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &newt);
          oldf = fcntl(STDIN_FILENO, F_GETFL, 0);
          fcntl(STDIN_FILENO, F_SETFL, oldf | O_NONBLOCK);

          ch = getchar();

          tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &oldt);
          fcntl(STDIN_FILENO, F_SETFL, oldf);

          if(ch != EOF)
          {
            ungetc(ch, stdin);
            return 1;
          }

          return 0;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

*My requirement is during the runtime of the program, If I press any key like spacebar or any other key, the program gets paused and once again I press the key, the program gets resumed.*

You can achieve this with this type of code

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  char i;int y=0;
  while(1)
  {
     if(!(_kbhit()))
     {
       y=0;
       printf("//key is not pressed");
       //do what you want
     }
     else
     {
       printf("key pressed (execution pause) , press again to resume");
       i=_getch();
       y=1;
     }
     if(y==1)
     {
       getch();
     }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: _kbhit(), _getch() where it is declared which means In which header files these are declared

Comment: @mohan header is   `conio.h`

Comment: @ameyCU conio.h is available only on windows. Iam using Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: You can send it to a function that again implements the same interrupt handling, instead of getch()

Comment: @mohan  Use `curses` then . See this question .Will be useful in this case -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3276546/how-to-implement-getch-function-of-c-in-linux

Comment: @ChristianidisVasileios nice :)