# How can i write text in c++ console without breaking the lines

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, console, cin

how can i input text in c++ console without breaking the input in one line at a time?
If i use cin i can input one string each time plus i cannot edit the input (except if i edit the string but this wont help)
Is there any way to input strings (with multiple lines) but not to break the string in one line at a time?

I am running ubuntu 12.04

Comment: No there is no way, since input is taken as soon you hit the ENTER key.

Comment: I think I know what you're doing but please show us some sample code so I can offer suggestions.

Comment: You probably could start a comandline editor and upon completion pipe the result into your c++ program. I've no idea how to do this exactly though.

Comment: You are missing a Linux tag, and I find your question bizarrely formulated. You should edit it to improve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Who is writing? Is it you, or some program??

<sup>Your terminology is unusual: generally programmers take the point of view of the computer!</sup>

What you write by typing on your keyboard is an *input* to some program (which *reads* it).

If you want an editable input (to the program, so "written" or typed by the human user), consider using [GNU readline](https://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html) (on Linux), or perhaps [ncurses](https://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/)

If you want to format the program's output (which the user would read with his eyes), you'll generally need to code that formatting explicitly. Perhaps [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) might be useful (but using them might make `readline` or `ncurses` unhappy).

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32392409/841108) and the references I gave there.

Comment: You could accept my answer if it fits. And you certainly should edit your question to improve it.