# Using left key arrow to move left instead of inputting characters with fgets

Tags: c

when I try to read a string with `fgets( line, MAX, stdin)`, I cannot use the arrows to move back and make correction; characters such as ^[[D are inserted instead. Is there a valid alternative to `fgets`.

This is the cycle I use to read the input:

```
char *buf = line;
char line[MAX];
printf("Enter x to quit\n>>");

for(;;) {

    if(fgets(buf = line, MAX, stdin) == NULL || *buf == 'x')
        break;

}
```

When `*buf = '^[[D '` is there a way to move the cursors left like the backspace but without erasing previous characters?

I'd like a solution that doesn't resort on external libraries such as `bash readline` but purely C ANSI.

Comment: Press backspace?

Comment: If you want to solve this without external libs, then this question is way too broad. That's far from trivial.

Comment: And any solution would be platform dependent since C does not require a keyboard to exist

Comment: Related, if not a dup: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32392409/6699433

Answer (score 1):

The fgets function receives a string from the input stream.  The relation between keystrokes and the input stream is entirely up to your operating system.

If the features provided by the OS are not suitable for you then you can use a console input library such as `ncurses`.

Comment: Hmmm, in one way this is the correct answer, but OP specifically said no to external libraries